# Visual Studio 22 EXE missing DLL

Tags: c#, visual-studio, console

I reviewed multiple responses from this platform about this new issue that I am experiencing and was wondering if there was a better way.

I created a Console application, utilizing DOTNET Framework 4.8 in the latest version of Visual Studio 2022.  I conducted a Clean and rebuild of the Console App to create its EXE file.  Then, I moved the generated EXE from the Release BIN folder to another folder on my Server for production. However, when I called and executed the EXE, I get an error that supporting DLLs were missing.  I am using SendGrid to send emails from within the EXE and did install the Nuget Package to support the SendGrid functionalities.

In order for the EXE to work, I had to also drag all the generated DLLs from the release folder.  This was never the case before.

How do I compile the EXE so it works as is into one single file?

Comment: "this was not the case before" - Absolutely not true, if you have used a Nuget package, then you definitely copied over those DLLs too.

Comment: You can publish your app directly to the server

Comment: @McNets That's just a way of automatically copying the files to the server

Comment: @DavidG I don't think OP can use 'dotnet --self-contained' with NetFramework 4.8

Comment: @McNets Correct, that's why I said all files need to be copied in my first comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for all of your answers and support.  After reading all of them, the Publish recommendation is the winner.  I was able to get just one exe file that I then transferred to my Server and it runs without issues on its own.  I am not being asked to provide the SendGrid DLL or any other requests.

The pic below depicts my Publish Settings for net6.0.  As a supporting document for this process, I also found the following article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/single-file/overview

[image]

Comment: Hi Johnny, glad to know you've found the solution to resolve this issue! Please consider  accepting it as an answer to change its status to Answered. It will also help others to solve a similar issue. See [can I answer my own question..](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), Just a reminder :)